# How can I retrieve data from my firebase database?

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have tried many ways to get data from my firebase database, but they dont work.
Is there any simple way to retrieve data from my firebase database?

my js code:

```js
var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "REDACTED",
    authDomain: "REDACTED.firebaseapp.com",
    projectId: "REDACTED",
    storageBucket: "REDACTED.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "474155068193",
    appId: "REDACTED",
    measurementId: "G-715TVNY07N"
  };
  // Initialize Firebase
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

  console.log(firebase);

  var database = firebase.database();
  var ref = database.ref('en');

  function lah(){
      var data = {
        kommentti: document.getElementById("viesti").value
      }
      ref.push(data);
  }
```

my database:

[image: I would like to know what is inside those kommenttis]

I would like to know what is inside those kommenttis.

Comment: Here you pushing records to firebase. you can check documentation https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#read_data_once

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the data just once without a listener you can use a function like this one:

```js
const getData = async () => {
  return firebase
    .database()
    .ref("en")
    .once("value")
    .then((snapshot) => {
      snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot) => {
        const childKey = childSnapshot.key;
        const childData = childSnapshot.val();
        const kommentti = childData.kommentti;
      });
    });
};
```